# How to add an assignment to a Planner task using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: angular, typescript, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the Microsoft Graph API to access my Planner tasks from Office 365 and have created an improved front end using Angular and the `@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client.  However, I have hit a problem creating new tasks.  I can create a new task, but I can't manage to assign it to a user.

My code looks like this:

```
async addTask(planId: string, bucketId: string, title: string): Promise < Task > {

    let postData = { "planId": planId, "bucketId": bucketId, "title": title };

    let result = await this.graphClient
        .api("/planner/tasks")
        .header("Prefer", "return=representation")
        .version("beta")
        .post(postData);

    // works fine up to here and creates the task

    let newAssignment = new assignment;
    let assignments = `{"${this.userId}": ${newAssignment}}`;

    let newTask = await this.graphClient
        .api(`/planner/tasks/${result.id}`)
        .header("If-Match", result["@odata.etag"])
        .header("Prefer", "return=representation")
        .patch({ "assignments": assignments });

    return newTask;

}

export class assignment {
    "@odata.type": string;
    orderHint: string;

    constructor() {
        this["@odata.type"] = "microsoft.graph.plannerAssignment";
        this.orderHint = " !";
    }
}
```

The first section works fine and creates the task with nobody assigned, but the second section fails with a `400` error "Property assignments in payload has a value that does not match the schema."

The newAssignments object looks like this:

```
{
  @odata.type: "microsoft.graph.plannerAssignment", 
  orderHint: " !"
}
```

I created the assignments class, following the answer to a similar question about C#, previously had just been sending a basic object, like this:

```
let assignments = `{"${this.userId}": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.plannerAssignment", "orderHint": " !"}}`
```

but that had also failed with the same error.

One question is whether you amend the assignments property using 'patch' or whether I should be adding an assignment using 'post'.  I've tried both and neither work.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to work it out in the end.  I don't fully understand the reasons why, so feel free to comment/answer if you have more insight.

The code as written was sending the JSON payload in the wrong form, so in fiddler it was appearing like this:

```
assignments = {"a5b71811-bc30-4cf2-99cf-8edc14aa96f8": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.plannerAssignment", "orderHint": " !"}}
```

Adjusting the code as below solved the issue:

```
let assignments = `{"assignments": {"${this.userId}": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.plannerAssignment", "orderHint": " !"}}}`

let newTask = await this.graphClient
  .api(`/planner/tasks/${result.id}`)
  .header("If-Match", result["@odata.etag"])
  .header("Prefer","return=representation")
  .patch(assignments);
```

This now sends the correct JSON representation, which appears as below in fiddler.  This works properly.  As you'll see, the assignment is submitted using 'patch' and not 'post'.

```
- JSON
  - assignments
    - a5b71811-bc30-4cf2-99cf-8edc14aa96f8
        @odata.type = microsoft.graph.plannerAssignment
        orderHint =  !
```